Manga where the main character is a foreign blonde girl working as a paperboy
I am currently looking for a manga which I read six years ago (no guarantee that it's actually written any time around that though), written by a lady who's at least ethnically Chinese.
The main character (MC) is an ethnically foreign (to the host country) girl working and crossdressing as a paperboy (one of the foreign traits she had is that she's blonde-haired and had blue eyes). A secondary protagonist is a robot named Crow, disguised as a boy and missing a arm. There's also a journalist named Hector. The story ends with Crow being sent on a rampage and shot down by the navy while the MC is awarded for bravery, given a medal that she promptly sold for cash, and moves out of country.
Does anyone have some ideas on what this manga might be? Thanks.

Is this the graphic novel, NewsPrints (2017), by Ru Xu...? There's a second volume, EndGames (2019).
A review notes that the protagonist, Blue, is an orphan who masquerades as a boy selling newspapers. She meets a strange boy named Crow and has a friend named Hector.

With her father away fighting in the war, Blue was left completely alone when her mother passed away. In order to get by, she began masquerading as a boy so that she could get a job selling newspapers and stay at the Mayor’s home for orphaned boys. While running away from a rival group of newsboys she attempts to hide in what she thinks is an abandoned building and runs into Jack, an eccentric scientist and inventor. He hires her as his apprentice and helps her to continue her education while she assists him with his experiments. While accompanying him to a meeting at the naval base, Blue gets lost and stumbles upon Crow, a strange boy who loves birds and seems to be afraid of being seen by adults. Blue befriends him and tries to get him to come home with her when she discovers that he doesn’t have any parents, but while Crow is happy to hang out with Blue and her fellow Newsboys, he stubbornly refuses to go to her house. Meanwhile, Blue’s friend Hector starts to get suspicious of Jack, who might be withholding information from Blue about his identity and his true reasons for coming to their city.

According to another review, Crow is actually a robot.

It turns out that Crow is a machine, a robot. But he is not a weapon. He’s only a kid, very much like Blue. So, she tries to help him. And in helping him, she gets courage enough to tell her secret to everyone. But it comes with a little price.

Blue is depicted as having short blonde hair and blue eyes on the cover.


gosh you guys are biological book searching machines) thanks! that's the one I'm looking for. never heard about the second volume, got to read it now
